# "Trusted memory" What does it mean?

Tags: memory, trust, trusted-computing, trusted-boot, secure-boot

It is often cited "to load from *untrusted* memory to a trusted system memory" when describing the secure boot process. I wonder, when can we consider a memory as "trusted"?

Comment: Can you provide a place where it is cited?

Comment: Also, have you looked this up? These are the top 2 hits: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/uefi-and-tpm/#tpm and https://pages.arm.com/rs/312-SAX-488/images/DEN0072-PSA_TBFU_1.0-bet1.pdf